# Midnight Commander on OSX.Opening files

Tags: macos, midnight-commander

I am using Midnight Commander on Mac OS X (version 4.8.13).
I have two problems and I would be very glad if you can help me:

> /opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh: line 134: wvHtml: command not
>   found
>
> /opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh: line 135: elinks: command not
>   found

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved through to edit mc.ext the path of ~/.config/mc

> ```
> # Microsoft Word Document
> regex/i/\.(do[ct]|wri)$
>         Open=open %f
>         View=%view{ascii} /opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh view msdoc
> regex/i/\.(doc|xls)x$
>         Open=open %f
> type/^Microsoft\ Word
>         Open=open %f
>         View=%view{ascii} /opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh view msdoc
> ```

and

> ```
> # Microsoft Excel Worksheet
> regex/i/\.xl[sw]$
>         Open=open %f
>         View=%view{ascii} /opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh view msxls
> type/^Microsoft\ Excel
>         Open=/opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh open msxls
>         View=%view{ascii} /opt/local/libexec/mc/ext.d/doc.sh view msxls
> ```